# replace line with single quotes by sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to change single line of config started with "option timezone" to a line with single quotes: "option timezone 'EST-10'". However when I do this

```
sed -i '/option timezone/c\option timezone 'EST-10'' /etc/config/system
```

single quotes missed and result is like this:

```
head /etc/config/system 

config system
option timezone EST-10
```

Of course backslash before quotes doesn't help. Can I achieve it somehow with \c command. 
P.S. sed is from openwrt busybox, limited, supports only e,f,i,n,r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/option timezone/c\option timezone '\'EST-10\' /etc/config/system
```

Adjacent strings are automatically concatenated by bash, so this closes the first string, adds a single quote (which needs to be escaped), EST-10, then another escaped single quote.

If the "EST-10" part contained spaces, then you would need to put it into single quotes too:

```
sed -i '/option timezone/c\option timezone '\''EST - 10'\' /etc/config/system
```

Double quotes are also an option but personally I prefer not to use them as there are a whole load of other characters that Bash will interpret, such as `$` and `!`, that then need escaping.

Comment: first one works, thanks! there were no spaces so no need in second way. also I don't know how backticks got there - I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single quoted string inside double quoted `sed` command without bothering to escape them:

```
sed -i "/option timezone/c\option timezone 'EST-10'" /etc/config/system
```